# Error after exporting and building a tensorflow graph

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

After i trained a model successfully, exported the graph with the freeze_graph.py and built it with the customized /tensorflow/examples/label_image/main.cc using bazel, i am getting following runtime error.

```
Running model failed: Invalid argument: Matrix size-compatible: In[0]: [150,4],
In[1]: [600,36][[Node: local3/MatMul = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false,
transpose_b=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"(local3/Reshape,
local3/weights/read)]]
```

I am pretty confused because all previous step has been successful and i am wondering about the [150, 4]. My batch_size is 150 and 4 is the number of classes, but why is this tensor an input for the matmul-operation in my local-layer?  This code is showing the local3 layer. The pool4 layer looks like this [150x10x10x6]

```
# local3
with tf.variable_scope('local3') as scope:
    # Move everything into depth so we can perform a single matrix multiply.
    reshape = tf.reshape(pool4, [FLAGS.batch_size, -1])
    dim = reshape.get_shape()[1].value
    weights = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights', shape=[dim, 36], stddev=0.04, wd=0.0004)
    biases = _variable_on_cpu('biases', [36], tf.constant_initializer(0.1))
    local3 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(reshape, weights) + biases, name=scope.name)
```

For the model I've used the cifar10-tutorial from tensorflow as a starting point. My local3 layer relies pretty much on the layer from the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i didn't understand the error but i have solved it by modifying the local3-Layer

```
# local3
with tf.variable_scope('local3') as scope:
    # Move everything into depth so we can perform a single matrix multiply.
    weights = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights', shape=[600, 36],
                                          stddev=0.04, wd=0.0004)
    biases = _variable_on_cpu('biases', [36], tf.constant_initializer(0.1))

    dense1 = tf.reshape(pool4, [-1, weights.get_shape().as_list()[0]])
    local3 = tf.nn.relu_layer(dense1, weights, biases)   # Relu activation
    _activation_summary(local3)
```

I've seen the local-layer definition in this repo
https://github.com/HamedMP/tensorflow_export_cpp_example

I'am wondering about the tf.nn.relu_layer() method, because it seemed not documented in tho API-Reference.